# Change IP address when wireless is on hotspot mode

Tags: ip, hot-spot

I want to share my ethernet connection by wireless. To do that I just select 'use as hotspot option' in network settings. It created a hotspot called Ubuntu that I could connect to with my mobile phone. But after creating the hotspot my computer's internet connection is lost. I looked up eth0's and wlan0's IP addresses using `ifconfig` command

- eth0 is 10.42.0.83
- wlan0 is 10.42.0.1

I think there is an ip conflict, because there is another 10.42.0.1 in the cable network. If i can assign another IP to wlan0 I think the problem will be solved. Is there any way to change the hotspot's IP?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as IP conflict for different Interfaces(networks), if you're using DHCP.
You could try finding rfkill on your logs to see if you have a "friend".